# Auto Read SMS/OTP using (codenameone)

Tags: codenameone

I would like to auto read the OTP send via SMS in my application, so that user does not need to do it manually.

Is there an API available for it.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Incoming SMS is a special case in Android and nowhere else. You can use native interfaces to grab such messages.